# Installing powerline fonts for zsh + Prezto theme

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, prezto

I am currently using Zsh + Prezto for my scripting shell configuration. I have been using the `sorin` theme but am a little dissatisfied with it. I'd like to switch to the [paradox](https://github.com/paradox460/prezto/blob/paradox/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_paradox_setup) theme!

It is supposed to look like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

I'm having some trouble doing that. When I switch to the theme, the symbols aren't able to load, so I get a prompt that looks like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

Notice the boxed question marks where there should be an edge border for the background or a branch symbol for the git branch. (Take a look at the `paradox` theme preview [here](http://mikebuss.com/2014/04/07/customizing-prezto/)).

I've seen [here](http://mikebuss.com/2014/04/07/customizing-prezto/) that I should install [Powerline patched fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) for the symbols to load in correctly. However, as I'm somewhat unfamiliar with the process, I would love some help installing it into my Linux machine.

In the [documentation](http://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html), it notes I should install via `pip`. When I run `pip install --user powerline-status`, my prompt is still unable to display the symbols the way it should look.

What else must I do, after running the installation, to display this prompt correctly?

*I am using a MacBook Pro with El Capitan*

Answer (score 4):

I've just done it for myself, do the following :

Run `./install.sh` to install all Powerline Fonts then go to your terminal prefences, change the non-ascii fonts to 'Anonymous Pro' in Settings -> Profiles -> Text -> Font.

Reload your terminal to be sure changes are acknowledged by your system, then just try this command : `echo "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"`, you should get the following :
[image]

Enjoy your new prompt

Comment: I have a similar issue, the arrows are not appearing. Can you tell me where you run the install.sh and where to find Anonymous Pro (I couldn't find it in my iterm)

Comment: Ok I managed to find out the answers, by downloading the powerline font on github (https://github.com/powerline/fonts) you then run the sh and proceed as you said and everything works like a charm, thnak you!!

Comment: Glad to hear your issue is solved, please upvote my answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: yep forgot to do that sorry !!